# Div element is not leading clicks through to enable drag functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

In my jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/68h7ya6f/3/ I have 2 Div's. One of it shall be a menu, the other one is at the end a SVG that is on the whole page. The SVG also has a zoom-event which shall be toggled everywhere if not a menu element is clicked.

Let's now come to the issue:

1. When I click and drag the mouse from the top left I actually select the menu div instead of the map div.
2. How can I manage that the area around the menu elements is completely transparent. I mean the **background-color none** does not seem to lead clicks trough the div.
3. The same issue I have on hidden elements by the way. The area where the div is is not able to clicktrough. So every time I have my mouse there and drag it, I select all the text on the site instead of moving my SVG element via drag&drop from D3.js. Okay the hidden element could be set with width and heigth to 0 at the start. But that's not a solution because that div shall also be transparent by it's elements click-able.

So I think overall it's the question: ***how can I get a div clicktrough-able and also drag&drop operation going through there***.

I already tried the following:

- *pointer-events:none;* (makes no sense because I want the menu clickable)
- *background:white; opacity:0; filter:Alpha(opacity=0);* (completely invisible instead of just the unused div space)

What I did not yet try:

- background:url('transparent.png');

### Example website with this issue:

http://lotrproject.com/map/ there you can see that when you click in the area under (BLOG, ABOUT, STORE) you are not able to move the map. Actually I have the same kind of issue.

So at the end how can that area be completely transparent. Thank you guys.

Edit: a intersting article about that: http://blog.pixelastic.com/2010/07/23/click-html-element/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So solution is to expand the menu with jquery instead of having a fixed width or heigth. This way the menu is always as small aspossible.

For sure that would be hard in the case of the lotrproject to do. Because there you have 2 lines of buttons. But there is currently no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I did a little bit of digging and eventually dropped to Google Maps to see how did they got away with this problem (Since you referred to a map website). I did some common Inspect Element tricks and found what was going wrong with your CSS. On Google Maps, the Search box (or `omnibox`) was actually laid hanging on place by margin with `absolute` positioning. In your case, when I did the same trick, I found that the `<ul>` tag was adding extra padding and margin to the menu. So I added the CSS reset and got this solution: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3k04deuk/) (do check the "Fiddle Options"). I think this would be the most minimalistic and optimal solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, well you moved it to another place. But in my case I still have the issue. Especially with something like from the lotr website where you have a big div but not everywhere elements. Did you manage to get it running there?

Comment: If you could show how your menu looks like, then maybe I can help. My whole point is that you wrap the div in such a manner so that the map behind it can be dealt with, i.e. only giving them the space it actually needs. In the LOTR Maps website, their menu has two divs, one above and other below it. And that's the problem. These two divs should not have one common parent div.

Comment: Actually my menu looks like the one from lort maps right now. But yeah that's a bad way. So I gonna rethink the menu and maybe do something else instead. Thanks.